# Doctrine Order before Group by

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Product OneToMany Feature

I want to get ONLY ONE result in Feature for each Product.

And I need to choose the best alternative in Feature, by using MAX, MIN.

For i.e. I have one result in Product, and 3 associations in Feature, and there is a "value" property in Feature, i want to get the Product, and the one Feature where the "value" is the lowest one between those 3 records.

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->select('b, MIN(b.value) as min_value')
        ->from('Feature', 'b')
        ->where('b.value = min_value')
        ->groupBy('b.product');
```

that is where i stopped. It returns only one row for Product, but i want many Products, and one Feature for each Product. Also it does not recognize the select alias in the where.

Comment: Can you please copy and past the actual error message?

Comment: it says min_value isn't a valid column. it does not accept aliases in where. That's a sql behavior, not doctrine. If you want to use it, you have to use a nested query in from/join, but doctrine also does not allow that.

Comment: Ah, I've encountered similar problem before. You need to declare that `min_value` as `HIDDEN` field: `select('b, MIN(b.value) as HIDDEN min_value')`. More about `HIDDEN` keyword: http://michelsalib.com/2012/03/04/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/

Comment: It stills fails if i try to use it in where. SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr_20' in 'where clause'
->where('b.value = min_value')

Comment: This actually suggests a column mismatch problem. Can you update you question with entities and database structure?

Comment: it suggests i'm trying to use an alias in WHERE, which is not possible. That's not a doctrine limitation, you can't use select aliases in where clause even in sql.

Comment: This has to be solved with `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.